# Jquery ajax succes is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have an issue with my ajax call, where success is not working as expected, I have checked console and my script on server side is retrieving and answer, also I have make a console.debug call in order to show the answer at the console and none happens. After read an dread I couldn't find the error. Could you help me on that?

**My ajax**

```
$.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'credentials.ajax.users_save' %}',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
                username: $('#username').val(),
                password: $('#password').val(),
                last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
                first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                address: $('#address').val(),
                phone_office: $('#phone_office').val(),
                phone_home: $('#phone_home').val(),
                expiration: $('#expiration').val(),
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                console.debug(msg)
                if ( msg == false || parseInt(msg) == 0) {
                    $.pnotify({
                        title: '{% trans 'Error' %}',
                        text: '{% trans 'There were a error, please try again' %}',
                        type: 'error'
                    });

                } else {
                    $.pnotify({
                        title: '{% trans 'Congrats' %}',
                        text: '{% trans 'User has been create' %}',
                        type: 'success'
                    });
                    $('#modalCreateUser').modal('hide');
                    window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000)

                }
            }
        });
```

**my server side function**

```
def users_save (request):
    try:
        if request.is_ajax() and request.POST:
            user_id = request.POST['user_id']
            s = get_current_site(request)
            print s.id
            u = User (
                      username = request.POST['username'],
                      first_name = request.POST['first_name'],
                      last_name = request.POST['last_name'],
                      email = request.POST['email']
                      )
            u.set_password(request.POST['password'])
            up = UserProfile(
                      address = request.POST['address'],
                      phone_home = request.POST['phone_home'],
                      phone_office = request.POST['phone_office']
                             )
            up.user = u
            up.site = s
            #up.save()
            u.save()
            return HttpResponse(True, mimetype='application/json')
    except:
        return HttpResponse(False, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: any syntax errors in the console log?

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what error or unexpected behavior do you now see?

Comment: NOne, no error syntax and the server side script returns True as answer on json mode. then console must show a line with "True" as I write my code, but no answer is write on console but the reqwuest show the True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have notice that I was answering

```
return HttpResponse(False, mimetype='application/json')
```

instead of

```
return HttpResponse(0, mimetype='application/json')
```

As True is django sintaxis, cause of that javascript and jquery couldnt parse it, then it doesnt know what to do, I have change that and this work well now

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a few syntax errors ....
I have marked them in your code below with comments

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'credentials.ajax.users_save' %}',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            user_id: $('#user_id').val(),
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            last_name: $('#last_name').val(),
            first_name: $('#first_name').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            address: $('#address').val(),
            phone_office: $('#phone_office').val(),
            phone_home: $('#phone_home').val(),
            expiration: $('#expiration').val() //, no comma here
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            console.debug(msg); // needed a semi-colon
            if ( msg == false || parseInt(msg) == 0) {
                $.pnotify({
                    title: '{% trans 'Error' %}',
                    text: '{% trans 'There were a error, please try again' %}',
                    type: 'error'
                });

            } else {
                $.pnotify({
                    title: '{% trans 'Congrats' %}',
                    text: '{% trans 'User has been create' %}',
                    type: 'success'
                });
                $('#modalCreateUser').modal('hide');
                window.setTimeout(function(){location.reload()}, 2000); // needed a semicolon

            }
        }
    });
```